# Locally connectedness and accessibility

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $\Omega$ to be a bounded area in the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ with a  locally connected boundary $\partial\Omega$, then every point of $\partial\Omega$ is accessible from $\Omega$.Here accessibility of a point $\omega_0\in\Omega$ means that there exists a continuous mapping $\alpha:[0,1)\longrightarrow\Omega$ such that $\lim\limits_{t\to 1^{-}}\alpha(t)=\omega_0$.

Actually this proposition is part of the proof of the Caratheodory Theorem of comformal mapping which states: If $f:B_{1}(0)\longrightarrow\Omega$ is a comformal mapping and $\Omega$ is a bounded simply connected area, then the following two are equivalent:

(1)$f$can be extended to a continuous map $\overline{f}:\overline{B_{1}(0)}\longrightarrow\overline{\Omega}$

(2)$\partial\Omega$ is locally connected

Of course, if we assume that the Caratheodory Theorem of comformal mapping has already been proven, then the proposition I asked above can also be solved by applying the Theorem. However, as I have said above, the proposition is used in the proof of Caratheodory Theorem of comformal mapping, so I am looking for a topological proof of the proposition.

Comment: Not sure if you're still interested, but this is all in Wilder's Topology of Manifolds.  I might drop an answer on here later.

Answer (score 1):

A topological proof of the accessibility result is given in the book, "Elements of the Topology of Plane Sets of Points"  (2nd ed., 1954) by M.H.A. Newman. Specifically, see Theorem 14.4 in Chapter VI, on pg. 164. It is not necessary that $\Omega$ be bounded; it suffices for $\Omega$ to be a domain in the complex plane (or even the extended complex plane), meaning that $\Omega$ is open and connected.

The proof depends on the preceding Theorem 14.3, which in turn depends on Theorem 14.1 (pg. 140), which is self-contained.

Newman's definition of accessibility is exactly as you have stated. His definition of a set (in a metric space) being "locally connected at a point", is given in paragraph 13 of Chapter VI, on pg. 159.

Comment: Actually, the Theorem listed in Newman's book is not talking about the same thing as stated in my problem. More specifically, Thm14.4 states that if $D$  is locally connected at $a$ , where $a$  is a boundary point of $D$ , then  is accessible from $D$ . However, in my post, I do not assume that $a\in D$ , and it's not hard to give a counterexample if we replace the requirement that $\partial D$ is locally connected everywhere with it is locally connected at only one point $a\in D$.

Comment: Actually, the definition of $D$ being locally connected at $a$, does not require $a\in D$. This might seem to be somewhat strange terminology -- and I tend to agree -- but that is what Newman adopted. I gave a citation for the definition but here it is: Let $E$ be a subset of a metric space $S$ and $a \in S$ (not necessarily in $E$). $E$ is said to be *locally connected* at $a$ if given $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that any two points of $E\cap D(a,\delta)$ lie in a connected subset of $E\cap D(a,\varepsilon)$. Here $D(a,r)$ is the open ball with centre $a$ and radius $r$. ...

Comment: ... So it seems that a possible discrepancy in notions boils down to whether $\Omega$ having a locally connected boundary (in the usual sense) implies that $\Omega$ is locally connected at each of its boundary points (in Newman's sense). According to Theorem 15.1 on pg. 165 in Newman's book, a simply connected domain is not locally connected at any *cut-point* of its boundary. (A cut-point of the boundary is one whose removal disconnects the boundary.)  Newman remarks on pg. 166 that this result is true even if the domain is not simply connected. Perhaps this can guide one to a counterexample.

Comment: You are right: $\partial\Omega$ being locally connected does not imply that $\Omega$ is locally connected at each point of $\partial\Omega$. Figure 55 on pg. 160 of Newman's book supplies a counterexample. There, one has $\Omega$ being the open unit disc with the y-axis removed. Clearly $\partial\Omega$ is locally connected. However, $\Omega$ is not locally connected at each point $p =(0,t)$ of $\partial\Omega$, with $0 < t < 1$ because for all $s>0$, the two points $x=(-s,t)$ and $y=(s,t)$ are separated in $\Omega \cap D(p,\varepsilon)$ if $0<s<\varepsilon<1/2$. ...

Comment: ...  I guess I should withdraw my answer; or do you think it has any value as a partial solution, under a different assumption?

Comment: In my counterexample (two comments prior to this one), I accidentally omitted the word "non-negative" before $y$-axis; so more precisely: $\Omega$ is the open unit disc with its intersection with the non-negative $y$-axis removed. Can you provide a reference for the theorem due to Caratheodory that you described, regarding the extension of conformal mappings?

Comment: The statement can be found in the article The Riemann Mapping Theorem Christopher J. Bishop. However, as far as I have discovered, most references only claim that there exists an continous extension without saying the extension is a surjection, which is exactly what I'm seeking for. Some references deals with the special case when the boundary is a jordan curve which is of course locally connected, but this case is somewhat too special that it can not be generalized. My teacher gave me a hint that this problem could be solved by applying the Wolff's Lemma and I am still a little bit confused.